# Ruby: Display HTML file in Memory Without Saving it to Disk

Tags: ruby, macos, file-io

I have an html report in memory and want to show it to a user without saving the report to disk. I don't have to worry about windows for now, so i've been making tmp files with ruby and  using system `open` to show the file.

```
report_file = Tempfile.new([report.name, report.extension])
report_file.write(report.text)
system "open #{report_file.path}"
```

While this would appear to work, it doesn't since the temp file is cleared from memory before safari/chrome can actually read the data (system returns once the command `open` returns which does not take into account the amount of time needed for safari/chrome/etc. to actually read the data.) To get around that i've been using `sleep 60` after `open`.

My question is this: Is there a better way to display a html file to the user without saving it than using tmpfiles? If not is there a way to wait for safari/chrome/etc. to read the file without using a `sleep` call?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid temporary files? The only alternative I can think of is making a GUI app and embedding a HTML rendering component which is a lot of work just to display a report.

Comment: Not avoiding temp files they just have limitations, asking for other solutions, or solutions to the limitations of the tempfiles. Writing a GUI would be over-architecting a solution.

Comment: Oh, Ruby's temporary files can't be set to *not* delete automatically? Odd. You could try getting a temporary filename with `system 'mktemp -t someprefix'` or looking for an interface to `mkstemp` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you don't hit some command line length limits or something, but there is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data:_URI_scheme

and something like this works even on Windows:

`firefox.exe "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="`

so try this:

```
require "base64"
report_text = Base64.encode64(report.text)
system "firefox 'data:text/html;base64,#{report_text}'"
```

Comment: `firefox: command not found` if i try `system "open /Applications/Firefox.app 'data:text/html;base64,#{report_text}'"` then it tells me it that the file: `'data:text/html;base64,#{report_text}'` does not exist.

Comment: I don't use Mac, just Linux, it should be the same. This works in irb: `system "/usr/bin/firefox 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='"` so try it with `/Applications/Firefox.app` instead of `/usr/bin/firefox`